# Handling touch start and touch end events

Tags: javascript, touch

I'm trying to make a canvas based puzzle game for touch devices and I'm struggling with touch events. I want the touchFunction to fire twice, once for the touchstart event and once for the touchend event with the appropriate x and y co-ordinates.

Below is what I have, it works fine for touchstart but nothing for touchend, can anyone point me towards what the problem is please? Any help would be great, thanks.

```
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchFunction, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', touchFunction, false);


    function touchFunction(ev) {   
    console.log(ev.touches[0].pageX + " " + ev.touches[0].pageY);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the `touchmove` event?

This will give you the x-y coordinate of where the current *'press'* is. Very similar to `mousemove`.

Comment: yes, but I only want the last location of the touch so how would I go about combining the last touchmove location with the touchend event?

Comment: Keep track of the last coordinates from `touchmove`. Usually when I'm writing these kinds of handlers the `start` event just indicates that I want to start listening to `move`, and `end` indicates that I need to finalize the last captured position.

Comment: ok thanks so I have a function setting the x & y positions on touchmove to variables which the touchend event can use. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into an abstraction layer like hammer.js, that way you can handle mouse events, and the various platform specific touch events: http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/